# Stack up CSS3 rotated flexible boxes

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm looking for horizontally stack up some rotated flexible boxes (i.e. `display: flex`).

The issue is when I rotate them, even when I set - for example - `height: 1em`, they stack up with a large space between each one.

My guess is that this is happening because when a box is rotated, it still occupies the non-rotated horizontal space.

How would you stack up rotated boxes horizontally and get rid of that undesirable margin?

In order to understand the whole problem better, [I've created a sample in *jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/3yGLy/1) and I'm going to paste the code here:

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inside">heyyyyyyyyyy</div>
    <div class="inside">heyyyyyyyyyy</div>
    <div class="inside">heyyyyyyyyyy</div>
    <div class="inside">heyyyyyyyyyy</div>
    <div class="inside">heyyyyyyyyyy</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.inside {
    min-width: 0;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);   
}
```

Comment: Just create an additional wrapper element for the text which you rotate accordingly while leaving the `.inside` elements untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your HTML and CSS like below. It is very difficult to explain everything here. [So Read this Article for More Explanation](http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span></div>
<div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span></div>
<div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span></div>
<div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span></div>
<div class="inside"><span class="test">heyyyyyyyyyy</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.inside {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1.5em;
line-height: 1.5;
min-width: 0;
transform: rotate(-90deg);   
}
.test
{
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
.test:before
{
content: "";
float: left;
margin-top: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bA2dE/1/)

### EDIT:

The above solution was working fine on chrome but not in FF. After `Matías Fidemraizer` had research on that and come with the cross browser solution. Thank you so much for him.

[**CROSS BROWSER SOLUTION**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yGLy/8/)

Comment: I'm going to give a try. I found a similar article (http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/01/css-rotated-text-parent-dimensions-and-spacing-issues.html) and I was working in the same direction. Thank you!

Comment: Check your demo! It's not working as you expected :\

Comment: which browser? i am checking in chrome and it is coming nicely.

Comment: Ah friend! I'm on Firefox latest version.

Comment: Check this Fiddle I did a minute ago: http://jsfiddle.net/3yGLy/3/ It "works" at least, but it requires `float` on `.inside` (inner containers). After lunch I'll try to get it working with flexible boxes. BTW, I'll look forward for your own conclusion!

Comment: Your solution is clean and much better than mine. Looking forward that how it will react on flex box.

Comment: Awesome. Kindly post your answer here.

Comment: I was thinking about if you would want to improve your own answer with my investigation, and mark it as the right one. Because I believe your answer isn't too far from my possible one.

Comment: suddenly i have checked your solution in chrome and not working. But it was a small correction that you have not added the transform syntax for chrome browser. I have just added and update my answer with that.

Comment: Ah yeah, we still need the -webkit- prefix...! Well done! Thank you for your effort :)